# Is it possible to explicitly specify template arguments in a generic lambda passed to a function?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++20, non-type-template-parameter

I want to create a compile-time loop over a small container (like 4-8 elements) with a size known at compile time.
It's not hard to create just one simple loop: I can create a template functor `F` with `operator()` overloaded and call it like in the code below

```
constexpr std::array<T, N> array{/*fill the array*/};

template <std::size_t index> struct F
{
    void operator()()
    {
        std::vector<T> some_container{/*fill it in runtime*/};
        some_container[index + some_offset] += std::get<index>(array); // Use safe array access
    }
};

template <template<std::size_t> typename F, std::size_t... I>
void iterator_implementation(
    const std::index_sequence<I...> /*unused*/)
{
    ((F<I>{}()), ...);
}

template <template<std::size_t> typename F>
void iterator()
{
    iterator_implementation<F>(std::make_index_sequence<array.size()>{});
}
```

Though, if I want to create ten such loops and want to conveniently pass a bunch of references with it (closure), I should definitely use lambda functions.
In order to use `std::get` in the lambda, I should use generic lambdas.
So, the functor from the example below may become

```
auto f = [&some_container, some_offset]<std::size_t index>()
{
    some_container[index + some_offset] += std::get<index>(array); // Use safe array access
};
```

I cannot simply pass this lambda to the `iterator` because it's impossible to pass a variable of a template type without specifying template parameters, and also I cannot simply get a type of the lambda and provide it as an `F` in order to call `F<I>{}` to recreate the lambda.
If I use `typename F` instead of `template<std::size_t> typename F`, I cannot call `f<I>` because `typename` has no template parameters, so cannot be used with them.

I can also pass `std::get<index>(array)` and `index` as ordinary arguments to the lambda function and avoid usage of template parameter but saving the safety of the access. Though, I wish to try using compile-time constants wherever it's possible in order to check how it works.
I believe that passing a compile-time constant numeric as a template argument may help the compiler to optimize my code more than if the number is an ordinary variable in my code (even though smart compiler should "see" this and optimize the call).
So, it's a question about new knowledge rather than discussing whether such an approach will help.

Is it possible to use generic lambda in a fold of parameter pack as I need?

P. S.
Despite the question title, it's not a duplicate of [How to pass generic lambda into function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56098005/1305036) because in my question template parameter should be specified explicitly, while in that question it can be deduced.

Comment: It's operator() that's a template, not the lambda. https://godbolt.org/z/rYTP1KTYc ?

Comment: @JeffGarrett, thanks a lot! I should've read the documentation more carefully. They literally say "generic lambda, operator() is a template with two parameters". Could you, please, answer the question as an answer, not as a comment? I wish to mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a generic lambda, `operator()` is a template, but the lambda type is not.

Instead of instantiating a template at an index `F<I>{}()`, one needs to instantiate `operator()` at an index. Since the lambda has captures, one will need to pass it instead of just the type as a template argument.

Replace:

```
template <template<std::size_t> typename F, std::size_t... I>
void iterator_implementation(
    const std::index_sequence<I...> /*unused*/)
{
    ((F<I>{}()), ...);
}
```

with:

```
template <typename F, std::size_t... I>
void iterator_implementation(F f,
    const std::index_sequence<I...> /*unused*/)
{

    ((f.template operator()<I>()), ...);
}
```

Full example: https://godbolt.org/z/rYTP1KTYc