# Why I can use a template function as parameter to std::sort but not a template lambda (with member function ptr as template parameter)

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

Sorry for the long title, as I stated this works:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct S { int a{}, b{}; };
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const S &s) { return o << '{' << s.a << ',' << s.b << '}'; }

template <auto ptr>
bool f(const S &a, const S &b)
{
    return a.*ptr < b.*ptr;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<S> v{{1,9},{2,8},{3,7},{4,6},{6,4},{7,3},{8,2},{9,1}};

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), f<&S::b>);
    //          Sort by S::b -----> ^^^^^

    for (const auto &s : v)
        std::cout << s << ' ';
    // output: {9,1} {8,2} {7,3} {6,4} {4,6} {3,7} {2,8} {1,9} 

    return 0;
}
```

But this don't:

```cpp
    …

    auto l = []<auto ptr>(const S &a, const S &b)
    {
        return a.*ptr < b.*ptr;
    };

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), l<&S::b>);
    //         Sort by S::b? -----> ^^^^^
    …
```

This is the error:

```
error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'main()::<lambda(const S&, const S&)>' and 'int S::*')
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), l<&S::b>);
                              ~^~~~~~
```

Looks like the template notation for the lambda as parameter for `std::sort` is taken as a comparison of `l` less than (`<`) `&S::b>`, that wasn't my intention.

How should I pass the template lambda to `std::sort` function?

Comment: `l<&S::b>` isnt a thing. `l` is an instance of a type with a templated `operator()`

Comment: `l<&S::b>` is simply invalid syntax: https://godbolt.org/z/dcTYxonM7

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. Please do not remove includes. They are part of the code. Anybody writing an answer will have to add them back if they want to test their code

Comment: Mhm, it's considered good manners to include the code in the form that we can paste and compile directly, and immediately see the error you're asking about. If the snippet is accompanied by a https://gcc.godbolt.org/, that's even better.

Comment: @AlanBirtles The duplicate targets don't appear to address this question. OP is not trying to *call* the lambda's operator(), but is instead trying to take its address. A duplicate that deals with taking the address of templated member functions would be more appropriate. (Also, why have you linked 5 different questions as dupe targets, 2 of which are themselves already marked as duplicates?)

Comment: @cigien I didn't add all the dupes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69428557/is-it-possible-to-explicitly-specify-template-arguments-in-a-generic-lambda-pass seems an almost direct match to me?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Ah, I didn't see the revision history, my bad. Hmm, that target is reasonably close, though that question is asking how to call the function, not how to implement the function itself, since that isn't an option for `std::sort`. Also, the answer below showing how to use the ranges version of sort makes me feel like this question could stand on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do this: `std::ranges::sort(v, {}, &S::b)`.

---

Your version doesn't work because `l` is not a template. It's a class instance with a templated `operator()`.

`&decltype(l)::operator()<&S::b>` would compile, but the resulting member pointer is not something that `std::sort` can work with.

It will work if you make the lambda `static` (`[](...) static {...}`, a C++23 feature), or if you wrap that expression in `std::bind_front(..., l)` or equivalent.

Honestly, if you don't want to use `std::ranges::sort()` for some reason, I'd do this:

```
auto l = [](auto ptr)
{
    return [ptr](const S &a, const S &b)
    {
        return a.*ptr < b.*ptr;
    };
};

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), l(&S::b));
```

Yes, this results in a stateful comparator (the member pointer isn't embedded into the type), but the syntax looks much nicer, and this should hopefully be optimized away.